# with the Twitter API - how can I get authentication for the engagement endpoint using a bearer token

Tags: python, api, authentication, twitter

I'm trying to get engagement data for my company's tweets for a marketing dashboard. I am able to authenticate with Tweepy to get basic Twitter feed data, but the engagement endpoint is giving me trouble. Is it possible that I messing things up by autheticating with Tweepy and then with the bearer token?

```
import tweepy
import requests
import json
import base64
import urllib.parse

consumer_key = <>
consumer_secret = <>
access_token = <>
access_token_secret = <>


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

print(api.me().name)


def get_tweet_ids():
    scandy_tweets = api.user_timeline('TwitterHandle', count=5)
    tweet_id_list = []
    for twit in scandy_tweets:
        json_str = json.loads(json.dumps(twit._json))
        tweet_id_list.append(json_str['id'])
    return tweet_id_list


def get_bearer_token():
    uri_token_endpoint = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'
    key_secret = f"{consumer_key}:{consumer_secret}".encode('ascii')
    b64_encoded_key = base64.b64encode(key_secret)
    b64_encoded_key = b64_encoded_key.decode('ascii')

    auth_headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(b64_encoded_key),
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
        }

    auth_data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        }

    auth_resp = requests.post(uri_token_endpoint, headers=auth_headers, data=auth_data)
    print(auth_resp.status_code)
    bearer_token = auth_resp.json()['access_token']
    return bearer_token



bearer_token = get_bearer_token()

bearer_header = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(bearer_token),
    'oauth_consumer_key': consumer_key 
}

recent_tweets = get_tweet_ids()

engage_data = {
    'tweet_id_list': recent_tweets,
    'engagement_types': ['impressions', 'engagements', 'favorites'],
    'groupings':  {'grouping name': {'group_by': ['tweet.id', 'engagement.type']}}
}

uri_28hr_endpoint = 'https://data-api.twitter.com/insights/engagement/28hr'
engagement_resp = requests.post(uri_28hr_endpoint, headers=bearer_header, data=engage_data)


print(engagement_resp.status_code)
print(engagement_resp.json())
```

When I call `print(engagement_resp.json())` I get the following output:

> 403 {'errors': ['Your Application ID is not authorized.']}

Comment: Related: https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/

Comment: Do you have access to the Engagement API? This is a commercial set of functions.

Comment: I used the Twitter application to get the key, token and secrets. Is there another step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in Andy Piper's comment. At the top of [this page on Twitter's Developer site](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/metrics/get-tweet-engagement/overview) it says:

> This is an enterprise API available within our managed access levels only. To use this API, you must first set up an account with our enterprise sales team

On [this page that describes the different levels of API access](https://developer.twitter.com/en/pricing) you can find out what's possible in the Standard (free), Premium, and Enterprise API tiers.