# Retrieving specific conversations using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have been trying to retrieve conversation threads using Tweepy, and although the functionality has been added to the Twitter api (conversation_id is an optional parameter), it has not been added to Tweepy. I was wondering if anyone was familiar enough with Tweepy that they might know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my code to get the conversation_id and also to download the conversations. Hopefully it helps people with similar issues. I have only included the required functions not the whole files, so I haven't listed the modules required like requests and base64, but they should be quite obvious.

The code to get the bearer token and create the header I got from here [with the Twitter API - how can I get authentication for the engagement endpoint using a bearer token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58943052/with-the-twitter-api-how-can-i-get-authentication-for-the-engagement-endpoint) but I reposted below for convenience

```
# returns a bearer_header to attach to requests to the Twitter api v2 enpoints which are 
# not yet supported by tweepy 
def get_bearer_header():
   uri_token_endpoint = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'
   key_secret = f"{twitter_creds.consumer_key}:{twitter_creds.consumer_key_secret}".encode('ascii')
   b64_encoded_key = base64.b64encode(key_secret)
   b64_encoded_key = b64_encoded_key.decode('ascii')

   auth_headers = {
       'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(b64_encoded_key),
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
       }

   auth_data = {
       'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
       }

   auth_resp = requests.post(uri_token_endpoint, headers=auth_headers, data=auth_data)
   bearer_token = auth_resp.json()['access_token']

   bearer_header = {
       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
       'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(bearer_token),
       'oauth_consumer_key': twitter_creds.consumer_key 
   }
   return bearer_header

# Returns the conversation_id of a tweet from v2 endpoint using the tweet id
def getConversationId(id):
   uri = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?'

   params = {
       'ids':id,
       'tweet.fields':'conversation_id'
   }
   
   bearer_header = get_bearer_header()
   resp = requests.get(uri, headers=bearer_header, params=params)
   return resp.json()['data'][0]['conversation_id']

# Returns a conversation from the v2 enpoint  of type [<original_tweet_text>, <[replies]>]
def getConversation(conversation_id):
   uri = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?'

   params = {'query': f'conversation_id:{conversation_id}',
       'tweet.fields': 'in_reply_to_user_id', 
       'tweet.fields':'conversation_id'
   }
   
   bearer_header = twitter_auth.get_bearer_header()
   resp = requests.get(uri, headers=bearer_header, params=params)
   return resp.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

Tweepy does not support v2 of the API yet, although there are [plans for this in the coming year](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1472).

2022 Edit: Tweepy *does* support the latest Twitter API at this time.

Comment: Thanks for that, I did manage to achieve it without Tweepy, I'm not sure if I should post here?

Comment: @LeeRobinson I really appreciate if you post your answer here as I have the same question thank you!

Comment: @mOna code is here! sorry it took so long it was Christmas ;-)

Comment: Another thing I noticed is the conversation id seems to always be the id of the original tweet so the getconversationid could be redundant